# Visual Studio showing false errors

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I was working on a project, and I usually before doing anything I create new branches.

In my feature branch, Visual Studio wasn't showing any errors. It was doing all good.

Well, I switched from my feature branch to my develop branch and it shows me errors when it didn't before.

But there are no errors, since I build the solution and it succeeds.
It runs perfectly.

[image]
[image]

First time this actually happens to me. :/

Answer (score 7):

It's because VS uses for editor other implementation then while building, and sometimes it fails to follow files modification. Sometimes it helps to reopen the solution, sometimes you should close the solution, remove cache files (they should be a file or subdirectory next to the solution file) and reopen the solution.

Comment: Thanks @max630! Only removing the cache files worked. Just re-opening the solution did not.

Comment: The cache is the hidden ".vs" directory next to the solution file

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when the .NET Framework for the referenced project was higher than the referencing project.

Comment: I recently installed VS 2022 nd it prompted me to upgrade my projects to .Net Framework 4.8. What I didn't realise it that it did not upgrade ALL projects and your suggestion helped me find that

Answer (score 0):

You may try to clean the solution, sometimes I have this problem and that is the solution. Go to Build > Clean Solution.

I hope this can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some **extension** issue. I am coding with Symfony/PHP, when I turned off every related extension the problem is gone.